# what is the directory structure in CircleCI tests?

Tags: circleci

In my CircleCI test config I have:

```
      - run: ./vendor/bin/phpunit Test/Unit
```

so it looks like I am inside the root folder of my package.

However when I do this:

```
      - run: cp ../travis/travis.composer.json drupal/composer.json
```

(leftover code from running CI on travis a while ago)

it fails because it can't find the travis folder.

Where am I?

How can I work with the folders in my repository? I need to run an integration test which needs to create a new folder and copy a composer.json file to install things.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed at the root of your repository if you've not specified otherwise.

It does not find `../travis/travis.composer.json`, since the `..` goes to the parent directory on the CI machine, and that obivously does not have your `travis/` files.

Comment: Argh, yes, stupid mistake, the '..' is leftover from when I had a `cd`. Sorry for the obvious question, I was used to how TravisCI put me in a weird directory somewhere else.

Comment: Doing `run: cd drupal` doesn't change the directory in a permanent way - following that with - run: pwd shows it hasn't persisted.

Comment: Each `run` command is ran as its own process, so the changed working directory won't persist: https://discuss.circleci.com/t/unable-to-change-present-directory-or-cd-cmd-ignored/12537/2